# Microsoft-Edge adding a random overflow while other browsers not (SVG)

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

I'm a newbie here, nothing special, just have a little bug with **Microsoft-Edge**, it adds a random `overflow-x` while there's no content passing the screen's/browser's width, tried it on different screens and resolutions and the problem still there.

Here's a link of what I've done, if you want to test it on **Microsoft-Edge** : http://microsoft-edge.thefreecpanel.com/

A photo : [Photo Showing overflow-x bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYiMs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably adding margins or padding.  Check those values and be sure to implicitly set them for the body and any container elements that are supposed to fill the body.  If that does turn out to be the case, consider using a reset stylesheet (just Google that phrase if you don't know what they are).  We shouldn't need them in this day and age, but Microsoft.

Comment: @Archer I was already using **normalize.css** , nothings seems to be working, removed all margin and padding, trying to inspect the whole page and didn't see something wrong, all browsers were fine.
I don't know what else to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set Margin to 0.

Make a test with code below and let us know whether it solves your issue or not.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0; /* This will stop the margin, setting it to 0 */
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```